# jssor image width overflowing div container

Tags: jssor

What does the jssor Javascript base its image width calculations on for the jssor_1 div id?

I am creating a jssor image slider using Blogger Code option (paid subscriber) to copy/paste in my website CMS. Created page here: http://lower-hudson-regional-information-center.echalksites.com/groups/41146/zlorem_ipsum_1/just_slides

In <1300 browser width (and phone sized) responsive modes I observe the image width appears to extend too far on the right overflowing its div container. Screenshot example: [screenshot with right edge overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUBjc.jpg)

Only possible issue I have been able to identify is that something is causing the Jssor Javascript to calculate an image width for the jssor_1 div id that is skewing the display of the slider on the page.

I am hoping a Jssor Javascript and/or CSS guru might lend their expertise in identifying the cause of this issue with using my jssor slider in my website CMS.

Answer (score 0):

You defined padding for the css rule 'social-content'.

Please move jssor slider out from <div class="social-content">